# How to get "data" rather than "results" with Django Rest Framework ReadOnlyModelViewSet?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, json-api

*I have read this question [How to generate JSON-API data attribute vs results attribute in Django Rest Framework JSON API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35357798/how-to-generate-json-api-data-attribute-vs-results-attribute-in-django-rest-fram#35493123) but the accepted answer does not work for me plus I have a situation not covered there.*

I am using Django Rest Framework (3.5.3) to provide an API end point. That end point is based on

```
class FruitTestReadOnlyViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    queryset = Fruit.objects.all()
    serializer_class = FruitSerializer
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
```

The data returned from there is fine except that it has a "results" attribute rather than a "data" attribute.

The [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35357798/how-to-generate-json-api-data-attribute-vs-results-attribute-in-django-rest-fram#35493123) I mentioned above suggests you do this

```
class FruitTestReadOnlyViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    queryset = Fruit.objects.all()
    serializer_class = FruitSerializer
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    renderer_classes = (JSONRenderer,)
    parser_classes = (JSONParser,)
```

but that makes no difference for me and in fact I already have global setting which I believe cover the render and parser aspects like this

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    ),
    'PAGE_SIZE': 10,
    'EXCEPTION_HANDLER': 'rest_framework_json_api.exceptions.exception_handler',
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS':
        'rest_framework_json_api.pagination.PageNumberPagination',
    'DEFAULT_PARSER_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_json_api.parsers.JSONParser',
        'rest_framework.parsers.FormParser',
        'rest_framework.parsers.MultiPartParser'
    ),
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': (
        'djangorestframework_camel_case.render.CamelCaseJSONRenderer',
        'rest_framework_json_api.renderers.JSONRenderer',
        'rest_framework.renderers.BrowsableAPIRenderer',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_METADATA_CLASS': 'rest_framework_json_api.metadata.JSONAPIMetadata',
}
```

So I'm interested to know if someone out there has done this recently and how they did it ?

---

BTW I have other API endpoints based on `ModelViewSet` which work fine and which provide a "data" attribute rather than "results" ... here's an example of one of those

```
class TreeViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows Tree to be CRUDed.
    """
    queryset = Tree.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TreeSerializer
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Tree.objects.filter(username=self.request.user)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

pagination.py

```
from collections import OrderedDict
from rest_framework.response import Response

class Pagination(PageNumberPagination):

    def get_paginated_response(self, data):
        return Response(OrderedDict([
            ('count', self.page.paginator.count),
            ('next', self.get_next_link()),
            ('previous', self.get_previous_link()),
            ('data', data)
        ]))
```

settings.py

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS':
        'path_to_pagination.pagination.Pagination',

}
```

if you only want apply this to class `FruitTestReadOnlyViewSet`,not change settings.py and set pagination_class for this class:

```
class FruitTestReadOnlyViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    pagination_class = Pagination
```

change default pagination's `get_paginated_response` method from `('results', data)` to `('data', data)` will fine.

Comment: Thanks ! I appreciate it. I can't try this out at the moment but there was something the concerned me. As far as I can see this will effect all API end points (ie those which are working fine currently). Is there some way I could apply the Pagination class just to the ReadOnlyModelViewSet one ? Thanks again.

Comment: I forgot to ping you in that last comment and now I can't seem to edit the comment to include your user id so ... would you take a look at my comment immediately above this one please ?

Comment: I forgot to ping you in that last comment and now I can't seem to edit the comment to include your user id so ... would you take a look at my comment immediately above this one please ?

Comment: Err can't seem to include your username in a comment - another attempt to do that .

Comment: Excellent, thanks for the update. I can't try it now but I will do so later. Thanks.

Comment: I have made use of this now and it works fine. Thanks for your help I appreciate it.